# Initialize Firebase Config inside the service worker file in public folder

Tags: reactjs, firebase, environment-variables, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

I am working on Firebase Cloud Messaging on React Js. My project works if I keep my service worker inside the public folder. However, it is not ideal to initialize Firebase Config in the public folder since the data would be easily accessible to anyone. Furthermore, the Firebase Config needs to be different for production and local/development environment, this is not possible if I keep it hard coded.

**How should I initialize the Firebase Config in the service worker? Is it possible to move the service worker to the root directory instead which is in the project scope so I can use environment variables instead?**

firebase-message-sw.js (Service Worker)

```
// Scripts for firebase and firebase messaging
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.0/firebase-app-compat.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.0/firebase-messaging-compat.js');

// Initialize the Firebase app in the service worker by passing the generated config
firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: "",
    measurementId: ""
})

// Retrieve firebase messaging
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
```

Registration of Service worker

```
getFCMToken = async () => {
    try {
        const registration = await navigator.serviceWorker.register('./firebase-message-sw.js')
        const token = await messaging.getToken({
            vapidKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_VAPID_KEY,
            serviceWorkerRegistration: registration
        })

        console.log(token)

    } catch (e) {
        console.log('err', e)
    }
}
```

Note: If I move the service worker into the root folder, I get this error:

> DOMException: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://localhost:3000/') with script ('http://localhost:3000/firebase-message-sw.js'): The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html').

Basically, it still tries to look for service worker inside the public folder instead of the new location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer on this link: [How to use process.env in a React service worker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62225339/how-to-use-process-env-in-a-react-service-worker)

So you have to install NPM Package `cra-append-sw` in your project.

Place the service worker in the root directory or any other location that you can access `process.env` from. Use these environment variables in your service worker to initialize firebase config.

Then, add these two scripts in your `package.json` file:

```
"scripts": {
  "prestart": "cra-append-sw --mode dev --env ./.env.dev ./firebase-message-sw.js",
  "prebuild": "cra-append-sw --mode build --env ./.env.prod ./firebase-message-sw.js"
}
```

Run the project and it should create a service worker in your public folder.